# Finding the bug on is odd

Tags: javascript

I was wondering why this code errors with `Cannot read property 'odd' of undefined`:

```
var numbers = [5, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1, 0, 2, 2];

let isOdd = function(number){
    return number % 2 !== 0;
}

var oddEvenCounts = numbers.reduce(function(counts, number) {
    let odd;
    let even;

    if (isOdd(number)) {
        counts[odd] = counts['odd'] + 1;
    } else {
        counts[even] = counts['even'] + 1;
    }
 }, {});

console.log(oddEvenCoutns(numbers));

// expected result
// counts = {
//   odd: 1,
//   even: 3
// }
```

Do you see where the error is? It basically points to counts[odd] and counts[even]

Comment: `counts` is undefined

Comment: didn't I pass it on reduce? (function(counts, number)???

Comment: Ok well then `odd` is set to nothing. Please also format your code. It's very hard to understand what is going on when you don't format your code.

Comment: // expected result
 counts = {
  odd: 1,
 even: 3
 }

Comment: I understand that. `counts[odd]` but when you do that `odd` is undefined. Maybe you are trying to do `counts["odd"]` or `counts.odd`?

Comment: Tried that actually. But I got this: "error"
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'odd' of undefined

Comment: I don't get it, what is `odd` supposed to be? Some magic variable that is "odd" ?

Comment: If you're trying to count, you generally do `let odd = 0;` and then increment with `odd++`

Comment: @JamesHedegon Which did you try? And what line are you getting that error on? You really have to provide more detail, and format your code. The help center goes over all of this.

Comment: Also, there are 4 odd numbers, and 5 even numbers, counting `0`, in that array, why are you expecting something else ?

Comment: Oh well -> https://jsfiddle.net/yc25rmnb/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to count the number of odds and evens in your list `numbers` then I'm either misunderstanding your intentions or your expected output is wrong.

```
// expected result
// counts = {
//   odd: 1,
//   even: 3
// }
```

Doesn't make sense when you have 9 numbers in your array. However, I think this problem is best suited as a [mapreduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) problem. Since you're applying (mapping) the same function, `isOdd`, to every element in your array and then reducing it to a single object.

```
let numbers = [5, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1, 0, 2, 2];

// good job, this looks fine! +1 strict equality operator
const isOdd = function(number) {
    return number % 2 !== 0;
}

// function to keep track of your odd and evens 
const sumEvenOdd = function(acc, cur) {
    if (true == cur) {
        acc['odd'] += 1;
    } else {
        acc['even'] += 1;
    }
    return acc; // make sure you return your resulting object so it doesn't lose scope!
}

let foo = numbers.map( el => isOdd(el) ) // determine even or odd
                 .reduce( sumEvenOdd,  {'even': 0,'odd': 0}); // sum even and odd!
console.log(foo); // {'even': 5, 'odd': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

step-by-step mapreduce

```
let numbers = [5, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1, 0, 2, 2];

function is_odd(number) { return number % 2 !== 0; }

function get_counts(numbers) {
    numbers = numbers.map(is_odd);                                            // map is_odd over xs -> [true, true, false, false, true, true, false, false, false]
    let odd_sum = numbers.reduce(function(sum, n) { return sum + n; }, 0);    // reduce sum of true values -> 4

    return { 'odd': odd_sum, 'even': numbers.length - odd_sum }
}

console.log(get_counts(numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numbers = [5, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1, 0, 2, 2];
var oddEvenCounts = numbers.reduce(function(counts, number) {
  if (isOdd(number)) {
    counts.odd++;
  } else {
    counts.even++;
  }
  return counts;
}, {odd: 0, even: 0});

function isOdd(number) {
  return number % 2 === 1;
}

console.log(oddEvenCounts); // { "odd": 4, "even": 5 }
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I added a brief description. First time posting here, I'm learning.

Answer (score -1):

Try this , You need to return counts

```
var numbers = [5, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1, 0, 2, 2];
function isOddNumber(number){
    return number % 2 !== 0;
}

var oddEvenCounts = numbers.reduce(function(counts, number) {
    let odd;
    let even;
    if(isOddNumber()){
        console.log(number)
        counts['odd'] = number + 1;
    } else {
    counts['even'] = number + 1;
    }
    return counts;
}, {});
console.log(oddEvenCounts); // this is not a function it holds the value from reduce
```

Comment: i just tried to solve this part of question which was asked - I was wondering why this keeps on Cannot read property 'odd' of undefined. Thanks anyway

Comment: well continue with down votes if you do not understand the part of help -
I was wondering why this keeps on Cannot read property 'odd' of undefined, i just gave him the idea rest he can fix.

Comment: But.... it's an answer that doesn't work? You've changed it to `counts['odd'] = number + 1` which makes no sense at all, and is just plain wrong.

Comment: as i told u it could be dummy as well, i just wanted to solve the part of why counts is undefined and he was not getting any outoup. Of course i could solve the the rest as well but that would be too much.

Comment: @adeneo then you have to change the question and second thing it is always good to get lead and then solve the rest for learning purpose. this is what i prefer u can change or update your question and of course can get working code.